# Is it possible to use {tikz-qtree} along with {qtree}?

Tags: tikz-qtree, qtree

I've already drawn too many trees with qtree, but I've discovered that I'll need tree-dvips to draw movements, and this package is incompatible with pdf. I saw that it's quite simple to draw syntactic movements with tikz-qtree.
Should I switch for another package for drawing syntactic trees, once and for all?
Any advice?

Answer (score 7):

I would definitely make the switch from `qtree` to `tikz-qtree`.  There's an extra package `tikz-qtree-compat` which implements some extra features found in the former package. It's included with `tikz-qtree` itself. You can't however, use the two packages at the same time, since they both define a `\Tree` command which is not itself wrapped in an environment.

The syntax of the two packages is identical, but with `tikz-qtree` you won't need any of the manual spacing `!\qsetw` commands that are sometimes needed with `qtree`.

You should have minimal problems converting old trees to the new package.  If you like linebreaks in node labels (which I use a lot) you should add

```
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
```

to your preamble, so that you can do this.

Comment: I guess I'll make the switch. Thank you very much.